# How to mark certain points on the track in Adobe Audition while recording?

Tags: audio-recording, adobe-audition, timecode, file-organization

What is the best way to mark or highlight certain points or timestamps on the track *while* recording an audio file in Adobe Audition?

This is mainly for relatively long recordings or interviews and such.

And if there's a way to do this while Adobe Audition is not the foreground window in Windows 10, or in other words, while one is using a browser or document reader to read a document, that would be super helpful.

Ideally, I'd like those timestamps to be accessible using any normal audio player, whether on the PC or the smartphone, with an app like AIMP, so I can "jump" to those points in a very long recording or audio file. However, I'll settle for a way to jump to those points with some sort "next" button within Adobe Audition if there's no way to do this for normal audio players, too.

Thanks for any help or tips with this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but just pressing the 'M' key will add a mark in your session while recording. Add as many marks as you like. Many different tools can use these marks for various things. The marks can be renamed if you like. You can jump from mark to mark.

I don't know of any sound formats that let you keep the marks as part of the sound output file and then use them during playback.